# Returning a Json object from c# to an Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am trying to return a Json object from a C# WebAPI method. My current c# code creates an IEnumerable type, populates the object of a class, then returns it to the JavaScript call. However it's returning a 5 element array rather than a single Json object of 5 fields.

What I would like to do is simply return a single Json object with 5 fields, in this format:

```
 {"domain":"localhost", "spaceName":"rz64698", etc...}
```

This way in javascript I can simply access each field as

```
 _domain = rzEnvParams.domainName;
 _space = rzEnvParams.spaceName;
```

The response object returned from c# (to my Angular service) is this array. i'm only showing two of five elements here.   :

```
$id: "1"
$type: "RgSys.Controllers.RgController+RzEnvParameters, RgSys"
clConfig: "C:\Rz\rz64698\master\bin\cl_config.xml"
domainName: null
envName: null
port: null
spaceName: null


$id: "2"
$type: "RgSys.Controllers.RgController+RzEnvParameters, RgSys"
clConfig: "null
domainName: null
envName: null
port: null
spaceName: "rz64698"
```

and so on until $id: "5"

Here's how I'm current accessing the array in javaScript (it works but I feel there's a more efficient way) :

```
   $http({
            method: 'GET',
            encoding: 'JSON',
            url: 'breeze/breeze/GetRzEnv'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            rzEnvParams = data;
            deferred.resolve(rzEnvParams);
            $.each(rzEnvParams, function(key,value){                    
                if (value.domainName != null) {
                    _domain = value.domainName;;
                }
                if (value.port != null) {
                    _port = value.port;
                }
            });                
        });
```

and here's the current c# code which return :

```
   public class RzEnvParameters{
        public string clConfig;
        public string envName;
        public string spaceName;
        public string domainName;
        public string port;
    }
  [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<RzEnvParameters> GetRzEnv()
    {
        string clConfig =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClConfig"].ToString();
        string envName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"].ToString();
        string spaceName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpaceName"].ToString();
        string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"].ToString();
        string port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();
        var razParams = new List<RzEnvParameters>{
            new RzEnvParameters{clConfig=clConfig},
            new RzEnvParameters{envName=envName},
            new RzEnvParameters{spaceName=spaceName},
            new RzEnvParameters{domainName=domainName},
            new RzEnvParameters{port=port}
        };


        return rzParams;
    }
```

Bottom line: how do I refactor that c# code to return the Json object rather than an array of 5 elements.

thanks.

Bob

Comment: It looks like you're returning a list of RzEnvParameters where only one property is set. Is there a reason you are doing that instead of just returning one RzEnvParameters object with all the properties set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're returning a list of RzEnvParameters where only one property of each is set. Is there a reason you are doing that instead of just returning one RzEnvParameters object with all the properties set?

```
[HttpGet]
public RzEnvParameters GetRzEnv()
{
    string clConfig = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClConfig"].ToString();
    string envName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"].ToString();
    string spaceName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpaceName"].ToString();
    string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"].ToString();
    string port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();

    var razParams = new RzEnvParameters
    {
        clConfig = clConfig,
        envName = envName,
        spaceName = spaceName,
        domainName = domainName,
        port = port
    };

    return razParams;
}
```

And that would change your javascript to something like this:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        encoding: 'JSON',
        url: 'breeze/breeze/GetRzEnv'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            rzEnvParams = data;
            deferred.resolve(rzEnvParams);
            _domain = rzEnvParams.domainName;
            _port = rzEnvParams.port;
            //etc
        });                
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

may be i am wrong here, but why are you creating 5 separate objects, rather than one object with all 5 properties set.

```
public RzEnvParameters GetRzEnv()
    {
        string clConfig =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClConfig"].ToString();
        string envName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"].ToString();
        string spaceName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpaceName"].ToString();
        string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"].ToString();
        string port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();
        var razParams = new RzEnvParameters{clConfig=clConfig,            
                                            envName=envName,
                                            spaceName=spaceName, 
                                            domainName=domainName, 
                                            port=port        
                                           };


        return rzParams;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to do something like the following.

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetRzEnv()
{
    string clConfig =     System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClConfig"].ToString();
    string envName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"].ToString();
    string spaceName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SpaceName"].ToString();
    string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"].ToString();
    string port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();

    var razParams = new {
        clConfig=new RzEnvParameters{clConfig=clConfig},
        envName=new RzEnvParameters{envName=envName},
        spaceName=new RzEnvParameters{spaceName=spaceName},
        domainName=new RzEnvParameters{domainName=domainName},
        port=new RzEnvParameters{port=port}
    };

    return rzParams;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON serializer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx. This is the one with .NET, but there are several out there. This is a simple code snippet to just illustrate the serialization.

```
// your code to set your list List<RzEnvParameters>, var razParams = ...
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RzEnvParameters>));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, razParams);

stream1.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
var jsonToReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: There are three great responses. Do I have to only choose one answer, or is there a way to credit 3 responders ?

Comment: You can only choose one as far as I know. ;)